# Using a case statement with an IN clause in a where clause - confused as to how this sql syntax works

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I was looking at this stored procedure and to be honest I have never seen this type of pattern before.
I didn't know you could somehow mix a case statement with a `IN` clause.

Is the below stored procedure written in the correct style?  Maybe it is just the formatting of it but how does this even work?

This will return 0 if User.Location is 0.
It will return 1 if User.Location has the value 1 and also the LocationTypeID's value is equal to SomeValue ?

```
WHERE
  (
  ...
  AND
  (     User.Location = 0
        OR ((CASE 
          WHEN User.Location = 1 THEN
                 User.LocationTypeId
          END
        ) IN 
         (
            SELECT SomeValue
            FROM other.table
            WHERE blah = 1
         )
      )
  )
  ) -- and
  ) -- where
```

Shouldn't the IN clause be inside of the case statements WHEN .. THEN block?

Comment: `CASE` *expression*. SQL Server (T-SQL) does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: They are using `X in (sub_query)` - the only confusing aspect is that the value of `X` is dynamic. If `User.Location` is `1` then X evaluates to `User.LocationTypeId`. If `User.Location` is  anything else then X evaluates to `NULL` - and `NULL  in (sub_query)`  won't evaluate to `true`

Answer (score 1):

`case` does not seem appropriate here. What you seem to want is boolean logic:

```
where 
    user.location = 0
    or (
        user.location = 1
        and user.locationtypeid in (select somevalue from other.table where blah = 1)
    )
```

Comment: good point.  Is it b/c the case only has 1 option so might as well remove the case and use what you have?

Comment: @coolbreeze: even if the `case` statement had more branches, it would probably still be preferrable to use `and`/`or` logic. These handle conditions (wich is what you want here), while `case` is there to generate a scalar result.